# Does Geth and Parity store blockchain in level db in same format?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, leveldb

If not, what are the diffrences?, for example geth db format is:

```
var databaseVerisionKey = new Buffer("DatabaseVersion"); // databaseVerisionKey tracks the current database version.
var headHeaderKey = new Buffer("LastHeader"); // headHeaderKey tracks the latest know header's hash.
var headBlockKey = new Buffer("LastBlock"); // headBlockKey tracks the latest know full block's hash.
var headFastBlockKey = new Buffer("LastFast"); // headFastBlockKey tracks the latest known incomplete block's hash duirng fast sync.
var fastTrieProgressKey = new Buffer("TrieSync"); // fastTrieProgressKey tracks the number of trie entries imported during fast sync.

// Data item prefixes (use single byte to avoid mixing data types, avoid `i`, used for indexes).
var headerPrefix = new Buffer("h"); // headerPrefix + num (uint64 big endian) + hash -> header
var headerTDSuffix = new Buffer("t"); // headerPrefix + num (uint64 big endian) + hash + headerTDSuffix -> td
var headerHashSuffix = new Buffer("n"); // headerPrefix + num (uint64 big endian) + headerHashSuffix -> hash
var headerNumberPrefix = new Buffer("H"); // headerNumberPrefix + hash -> num (uint64 big endian)
var blockBodyPrefix = new Buffer("b"); // blockBodyPrefix + num (uint64 big endian) + hash -> block body
var blockReceiptsPrefix = new Buffer("r"); // blockReceiptsPrefix + num (uint64 big endian) + hash -> block receipts
var txLookupPrefix = new Buffer("l"); // txLookupPrefix + hash -> transaction/receipt lookup metadata
var bloomBitsPrefix = new Buffer("B"); // bloomBitsPrefix + bit (uint16 big endian) + section (uint64 big endian) + hash -> bloom bits
var preimagePrefix = new Buffer("secure-key-");      // preimagePrefix + hash -> preimage
var configPrefix = new Buffer("ethereum-config-"); // config prefix for the db
var BloomBitsIndexPrefix = new Buffer("iB"); // BloomBitsIndexPrefix is the data table of a chain indexer to track its progress // Chain index prefixes (use `i` + single byte to avoid mixing data types).
```

```